# What does the Alter Table syntax look like for adding a DATETIME column?

Tags: sql, mysql, alter-table, default-constraint

I can't find what the syntax looks like for adding a DATETIME column to a mysql table when I want to set the default to - example - 2011-01-26 14:30:00

Does anyone know what that syntax looks like?

Here's what I've got

```
ADD COLUMN new_date DATETIME AFTER preceding_col,
```

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you ever have doubts, the syntax is explained here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable 
  ADD COLUMN new_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 20110126143000 AFTER preceding_col
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable 
  ADD COLUMN new_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '2011-01-26 14:30:00' AFTER preceding_col
```

(I just prefer the numeric DATETIME format)

Comment: How do you get NULL to be no? When I ran my test, NULL was set to Yes

Comment: NOT NULL goes between datatype and DEFAULT value, as explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 12):

```
ALTER TABLE  `yourTable`
ADD `new_date` DATETIME NOT NULL
DEFAULT '2011-01-26 14:30:00'
AFTER `preceding_col`
```