# I want to insert datetime to database by converting the format to 'DD-MM-YYYY'

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, formatting

I'm trying to insert a date to mysql database by converting date format to 'DD-MM-YYYY'

```
ALTER TABLE tblleave
  ADD COLUMN DATEPOSTED DATE NOT NULL FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYY';
```

it shows a syntax error

Comment: Please post the actual error message

Comment: I do not see "format" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810066/what-does-the-alter-table-syntax-look-like-for-adding-a-datetime-column

Comment: fixed typo, added tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work. You can not format the value at INSERT or while defining your table.

You can either parse your custom format before inserting, or apply a formatting when you read back the value. This is what the FORMAT clause actually does.

You could do

```
SELECT DATEPOSTED FROM tblleave FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYY';
```